# How can I remove fields from WTF form by name

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, wtforms, flask-admin

I am trying to remove some fields from a wtf form:

```
form = super().edit_form(obj=obj)
for f in form:
    if f.name not in self.form_details_columns:
        del f
return form
```

This method doesn't work, however if I use something like

```
   del form.questin
```

Where `question` is the name of a field, it works

Comment: The `del` keyword removes the specified index (`del list[index]`). Assuming your `form` contains list of fields, you can iterate using `enumerate` and check for the value and use `del` to remove the value from that index.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove some of the WTF fields by using the del statement. the example I made is...

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name')
    age = IntegerField('Age')

# Remove the "age" field from the form
form = MyForm()
del form.age
```

you are able to use 'pop' to remove fields too.
Example:

```
form._fields.pop('age')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on other answers, I solved it using:

```
form = super().edit_form(obj=obj)
form_columns = [f.name for f in form]
for name in form_columns:
    if name not in self.form_details_columns:
        form._fields.pop(name, None)
return form
```